# Angular Material Component shows nothing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Angular Material doesn't show anything, when i use a Component.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSliderModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<mat-slider min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1"></mat-slider>
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: No, there are no errors

Comment: Did you specify a theme as [documented on the documentation site](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)? Additionally, can you please provide a [mcve]? The information you've provided is not enough to troubleshoot with.